# Hide the image, without the borders

Tags: css

I have a simple img tag:

```
<img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="">
```

And I have these styles for it:

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

I want somehow only with css, to hide the image, without hiding the border. And these styles have to be applied only for the image (.image{} selector). This mean that it have to be done without any wrappers.

I know that it sound a little bit strange and unnecessary, but I need it.

I've tried the following:

- "visibility" and "opacity" properties, but they hide the image and the border.
- Using the rgba() for the border color, and "opacity" and "visibility" again.
- Putting "opacity = 0" for the image and try to make the borders with ::before and ::after, but I saw that these don't work for the  tags, because they are empty by default.

Comment: "*only with css*" - Is this a constraint you can't avoid? Unsure if this will be solveable purely with CSS. If you can change the HTML, I would recommend placing the image in a wrapper div and give that the borders, instead of applying borders directly to image and use `visibility: hidden` on the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mask:

```css
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 10px solid red;
  
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0),
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box;
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,pink, lightblue)
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set element width and height to be `0px`, but add padding, to keep element dimensions. Than image will be not visible, element will have dimensions and border applied:

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
}

.image {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="">
```

Comment: That's a clever "hack" - Was worried first because I was thinking that OP wants to "reveal" the image later, but setting the padding to zero and applying the desired width/height smoothly reveals the image as well